# Помогите найти книгу

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Всем добрый день
Хочу почитать эту книгу, но только с примерами на c# - подскажите, есть издание этой книги с примерами на c#, ну или похожая книга

Банда Четырех. Приемы объектно-ориентированного проектирования. Паттерны проектирования.

Авторы - Э. Гамма Р. Хелм Р. Джонсон Дж. Влиссидес

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую ознакомиться с книгой Сергея Теплякова - "Паттерны проектирования на платформе .NET"

В ней есть много доступных примеров на C#

Книга читается легко. Для меня в плане восприятия легче, чем Банда Четырех

Comment: Автор книги, кстати, является участником ruSO: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178188/sergey-teplyakov Просто для информации.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию)